# Cordova - JS - Build doesn't seem to work after changing the JS file

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am using cordova 6.2.0

Targeted platform is Android, SDK API Level: 15 - 19,

Here's the code for index.js file

```js
var app = {
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
// var database = {
//   var myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(
//     {name: "mySQLite.db", location: 'default'});
//
//   myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
//     transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS phonegap_pro (id integer primary key, title text, desc text)', [],
//     function(tx, result) {
//       alert("Table created successfully");
//     },
//     function(error) {
//       alert("Error occurred while creating the table.");
//       });
//   });
//
//   var title="sundaravel";
//   var desc="phonegap freelancer";
//   myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
//     var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO phonegap_pro (title, desc) VALUES (?,?)";
//     transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [title,desc],
//     function(tx, result) {
//       alert('Inserted');
//     },
//     function(error){
//       alert('Error occurred');
//     });
//   });
// }
// database.initialize();
};

app.initialize();
```

Whenever I change the js file with the Commented code or any code the build is not working, always showing connecting to device and not doing anything.

[Stuck there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhkDZ.png)

I used the code from a tutorial, link: http://phonegappro.com/tutorials/phonegap-sqlite-tutorial-with-example-apache-cordova/

Here's the index.html file as requested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PS: I am new to Cordova, please let me know If I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: what does the build log say? `cordova build android --verbose` (change `android` to target platform (`ios`, etc))

Comment: The build is not working in the sense there are no errors in gradle build, but when I run the app the Device is ready option is never showing, only connecting to device is blinking.

Comment: JS seems okay. can you add HTML to your question ?

Comment: Sorry, I know Android is your target platform, but can you try if it has the same result with browser?

Comment: add browser platform and run it.see if you find an error.

Comment: @Yash is your sqlite plugin added without any errors?

Comment: @ArpitVasani Nope still not working still stuck at connecting to device

Comment: @YashAgarwal open `platforms/android` folder in android studio and run it from there then check the logcat.

Comment: @Gandhi --that wasn't the problem there was a missing '}' So silly of me, Yeah I haven't added browser platform, Thanks to Arpit, there are 2 plugins? cordova-sqlite-(plugin/storage) it's only working with storage.

Comment: @YashAgarwal Glad it worked. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    createDatabase();

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
```

I have created seperate function for database entry calling it from receivedEvent function and also made some changes into createDatabase() function as define below, and this is working fine now, tested into my own cordova app so please have a look and let me know if you require any change.

```
function createDatabase()
{
    try{
        var myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "mySQLite.db", location: 'default'});

        myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS phonegap_pro (id integer primary key, title text, desc text)', [],
            function(tx, result) {
                alert("Table created successfully");
            },
            function(error) {
                alert("Error occurred while creating the table.");
            });
        });

        var title="sundaravel";
        var desc="phonegap freelancer";

        myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
            var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO phonegap_pro (title, desc) VALUES (?,?)";
            transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [title,desc],
            function(tx, result) {
                alert('Inserted');
            },
            function(error){
                alert('Error occurred');
            });
        });
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked with some help from the comments and this post.